# Android : Hide specific views in the screenshot

Tags: android, flag-secure

I saw that we can disable screenshot of a window using the flag WindowManager.LayoutParams#FLAG_SECURE. I see that we can set secure flag for SurfaceViews. Is it possible to hide a specific view like TextView from appearing in the s screenshot

Comment: AFAIK `FLAG_SECURE` is an "all or nothing" feature on a per-window basis.